# Missing spotify album image from top bar pop up menu

Tags: gnome, spotify

I'm not seeing the album image in the top bar's pop out menu (I'm unsure what the actual name of this is...).

I recall it was there previously but can't remember when it disappeared.

Missing ablum art
[image]

In the screenshot I have both Spotify and Rhythmbox open to confirm it's only happening for Spotify.

Maybe it's theme related but the issue persists even when setting everything back to defaults.

Current themes
[image]

System is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME is 3.6.2

**Edit**:
Have set shell to Default theme, no effect
Have uninstalled the snap version of Spotify and reinstalled by package, no effect

Comment: when you change shell theme to default whats happening?

Comment: Shell theme does update to default correctly however, the album image is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify's album art missing isn't any fault of your desktop, it's due to Spotify using the wrong URL to get album art from.

Related bug report: [Album art missing from notifications](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Album-art-missing-from-notifications/m-p/4924475/highlight/true#M19480)